# Is it possible to run 64bit code on 32bit OS with 64-bit processor?

Tags: x86-64

We can transit from 32-bit to 64-bit mode on 64-bit OS changing CS register to 0x33 and align stack accordingly.

Is it possible to do the same, but for 32-bit OS running on 64-bit processor? I tried, but got an access violation. It seems, CS register is 0x1B on 32-bit OS, which is different from 0x23 on 64-bit OS.

Comment: The first trick (called *heaven's gate* in the infosec industry) is possible because a 32-bit app is really running in compatibility mode, a subset of the long mode (64-bit). If the OS doesn't go to 64-bit mode in the first place, you cannot expect it to have selectors to 64-bit segment descriptors. If you want to write a kernel driver you can, in **theory**, run a 64-bit app on a 32-bit OS (on a 64-bit processor) but that would be very very cumbersome. Absolutely not worth or recommended.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, thank you for your answer. Could you please provide me with some tech literature about the topic?

Comment: The table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes may help you understand the difference between compat sub-mode of long mode vs. legacy mode.  Also, those constants like `0x33` depend on what the OS has put in the GDT; the hardware itself only treats them as an index into the GDT (and the low 2 bits as a privilege level, i.e. ring 3 in this case.)